# Every single time I run the Emulator, I lose huge amount of disk space. How can I relocate where the avd folder stores the emulator files?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Essentially, at the moment the android studio avd stores everything in my C: folder, how can I relocate it to D: (D: folder being the bigger part with much more space).

Answer (score 2):

Try looking in C:\users\UserName\Appdata\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator. If the emulator doesn't shut down cleanly, you get some pretty hefty .tmp files left in that folder. You can delete these temp files to free up the disk space

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind adding little more content to the answer.